# Reading echo in the PHP script with getInputStream in the HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android, inputstream

I want to output the echo of the PHP script in the logcat but nothing comes back. The JSON String `{"mac": "10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9", "latitude":84.16898451,"longitude":3.16561387,"route": 1}` is there in the doInBackground method I can see it in the output. The output of the getResponseCode is `200` but I am trying now to read the echo of the PHP script but nothing is appearing the Logcat.

On the server side the table is being created but no data is being inserted into it.

doInbackground method:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground " + params[0]);

            URL myUrl = new URL("http://byethost.com/index.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.connect();

            System.out.println("The output of getResponsecode: "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(params[0]);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder: "
                    + sb.toString());

            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                    return null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

PhP script:

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( 'php://input', true ) );
 $con = new mysqli ( "domin.com", "username", "password", "database" );


$mac = $data->{'mac'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};
$route =   $data->{'route'};

// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES like 'bus' " ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {$sql = "REPLACE INTO bus(mac, route, latitude, longitude)
          VALUES( ?, ?, ? , ? )";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

  if(false === $stmt){
    echo "prepare()  failed: ";
  }

  $rc = $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$mac,$route, $latitude,$longitude);
 echo $rc;
  if ( false===$rc ) {
  echo "bind_param() failed: ";
}

  $rc = $stmt->execute();
echo "execute failed.";
  if ( false===$rc ) {
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
  }

  $stmt->close();

  echo "Table exist";
} else {
  $create =  "CREATE TABLE bus
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        route int(11) ,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL , 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" ;
   $stmt = $con->prepare($create) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: try to execute url in browser through any extension by passing necessary data. check what is the output. may be there is problem in php code

Comment: @Guru I am getting `execute() failed: Column 'mac' cannot be null` but column mac is NOT NULL !? It is NOT NULL . What does that mean?

Comment: @Guro: And why I am not getting that in my getInputStream reader?

Comment: Now you are trying to read the echos of the php script as i several times asked you to do in the other post. But also here you have an IOException. A ProtocollException.

Comment: @greenapps I corrected it as `user2340612` proposed.

Comment: @greenapps: but what I cant understand is why the data is not being sent to the server? please any hints

Comment: That is not true. Your Android code sends all perfect to your script.

Comment: @greennapps but why is the data is not being inserted into the table although I tested my PHP script in the localhost server without the device before and it works well?

Comment: I deleted the die method and added echo instead there and I am getting the echo that `execute failed`.

Comment: Which execute ? Cant you be more to the point?

Comment: ` $stmt->execute()` this method returns false.

Comment: How should i know what it does?

Comment: What you should do is remove all code from your script. Or better place it in a comment. Put only following code line in it: `echo( file_get_contents ( 'php://input', true ) );`. Now that you read the response from the script you will see what it received.

Comment: @greenapps: I am getting `The output of the StringBulder: echo( file_get_contents ( 'php://input', true ) );` I thought I will get the JSON string.

Comment: You forgot the <?php ......... ?>  start and end tokens?

Comment: I need some coffe. Yes I am receiving it. That means the error it somewhere in the PHP file.